# Cookies carrying Session identifiers

Tags: cookies, session-management

Is there a list of names for cookies carrying SID's? For instance:

- PHP by default uses PHPSESSIONID
- Tomcat uses JSESSIONID
- ...

I would like to be able to intercepts all SID's supplied via Cookies, of websites I visit. I could use heuristics like:

- HttpOnly attribute set
- Secure attribute set (not always the case)
- The name contains the string "ID" or "SESSION"

Has anyone done this kind of research before?

Thanks!

Comment: Many frameworks allow you to specify the session cookie name. You'll never be able to get those.

Comment: How are you planning on intercepting? What are you trying to achieve?